# How to create a naive location service for building specific accuracy

Tags: android, geolocation, router, wifi

I want to build a prototype app that allows users to rope off a building such that when others open the app in that roped off area they can be located to that building without fail. Current geolocation services have many toss up scenarios that fail widely in many cases.

What could be a naive approach to overcoming this by potentially adding an additional service (like a simple wifi heat mapper) to clear up some of the location ambiguity in order to create a reliable bound over the location? Are their any APIs in existence to help with such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about some specific buildings or any building that the user has entered? In the first case I would use beacons or IndoorAtlas. Both methods require you to visit the buildings and either install beacons or map it up with IndoorAtlas. With beacons it would be enough just to place one on each exit to keep track of who enters and exists the building.

There's really no possible way to reach building-level accuracy with a method that would be possible the extend to any building. The only exception would be some public buildings, which Google has mapped indoors (read more about the Google indoors project [here](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685872?hl=en&ref_topic=1685871&vid=1-635754719569769126-1501699312222276287)). However, the list of available locations is still really limited.

Even though not optimal, the easiest way would be to use GPS/core-location for this project. According to our experiments, GPS never shows your location inside the building, where you are currently, but always about 15m outside of it. You could try placing a geofence that is slightly larger than the building itself outside of the locations you wish to use.

Whichever technology you end up using, you can try the [Proximi.io](http://proximi.io) API for a super simple solution of keeping track of the locations and geofences/beacons.

Comment: Ideally I'd hope that the service could be extended to any building that has a basic outline on the map(or maybe even a basic floor plan) and within a city that is also relatively outlined. Its getting past the toss up scenarios that would be great.

Comment: Also to answer your question - its for any building that a user would to attempting to manually fill in the gap by potentially doing some sort of heat mapping.